# UIActivityIndicatorView not working on programmatically UIWebView in mySubView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

My myViewController.h contains:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController {

    UIScrollView *myScrollView;

    UIView *mySubView;

    UIWebView *myWebView;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;

@end
```

My myViewController.m contains:

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@implementation myViewController

@synthesize myScrollView;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *bgColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < bgColors.count; i++)
    {
        CGRect frameNew;
        frameNew.origin.x = self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frameNew.origin.y = 0;
        frameNew.size = self.myScrollView.frame.size;

        mySubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameNew];
        mySubView.backgroundColor = [bgColors objectAtIndex:i];

        [self.myScrollView addSubview:mySubView];

        myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        myIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 100);
        myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;

        CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, 320, 320);
        myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
        [myWebView setDelegate:(id)self];
        [myWebView addSubview:myIndicator];

        NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

        [self.myScrollView addSubview:myWebView];

        [myIndicator release];
        [myWebView release];
        [mySubView release];
    }

    self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * bgColors.count, self.myScrollView.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Web view did start loading");
    [myIndicator startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Web view did finish loading");
    [myIndicator stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [myIndicator stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSString* errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>", error.localizedDescription];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:errorString baseURL:nil];
}

...
```

Load indicator does not work on the first two `mySubView` in `myWebView`, works only on the last `mySubView` in `myWebView`.

In the first two `mySubView` in `myWebView`, `myIndicator` displayed but not active.

Tell me what's wrong doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `myIndicator` is pointing to the last activity indicator view. All previous references are lost. Luckily, since it is a subview of the web view, we can get a reference to it. This should help –

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *actView;
    for ( id object in webView.subviews ) {
        if ([object isMemberOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
            actView = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)object;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Web view did start loading");
    [actView startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *actView;
    for ( id object in webView.subviews ) {
        if ([object isMemberOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
            actView = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)object;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Web view did finish loading");
    [actView stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *actView;
    for ( id object in webView.subviews ) {
        if ([object isMemberOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
            actView = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)object;
        }
    }
    [actView stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSString* errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>", error.localizedDescription];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:errorString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: And your last reference is unreliable as you have released it at the end of the for loop. You have relinquished ownership so it could point to garbage. It still works because the web view object has kept the object alive by retaining it as its subview.

Comment: I didn't get you. Solution for what? Isn't the code working for you? what is the error you are getting.

Comment: Immediately I saw your code.. Yes all working... Thank you very much, very helpful...